# Why class Fields result in Empty JSON response data?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Action in my Web api controller That returns an instance of **SampleClass**.
when SampleClass has **Fields**, the result of Action is this: {}

and when i replace my Fields with **Properties** the result is afilled Json as expected.
Can any one explain Why this is Happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Serialization only works on Properties by default, that is one of the main reasons to choose between using *Fields* or *Properties*

As a C# developer I assume you've read [Why Properties Matter](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/PropertiesMatter) (by the illustrious  [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet))

Comment: I have been working c# in Unity3d for a time.now in asp.net i face some basic challenges

Answer (score 1):

For response serialization your application is probably configured to use `System.Text.Json`, which by default ignores fields as described here: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#serialization-behavior)

However you are able to make fields serializable by adding corresponding attribute: [another link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#include-fields)